# Postgres + Heroku SSL SYSCALL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Ocassionally my Rails app that is hosted on Heroku will go down and I am not sure what is happening. Sometimes many request timeout errors may happen beforehand. Then I get this error:
Does anyone have any idea what may be happening or how I might further look into this issue?

```
NilClass# (PG::Error) "SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected\n"


/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:294:in `exec'/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:294:in `dealloc'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:278:in `block in clear'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:277:in `each_value'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:277:in `clear'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:339:in `clear_cache!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:352:in `reconnect!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:219:in `verify!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:333:in `block in checkout_and_verify'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__2596940609290925681__checkout__3309272650293367200__callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_checkout_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:332:in `checkout_and_verify'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1965518221808316025__call__3309272650293367200__callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/static.rb:119:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following link might be a starting point:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#pgerror-ssl-syscall-error-eof-detected

In particular the following excerpt:

> These errors indicate a client side violation of the wire protocol. This happens for one of two reasons:
>
> - The Postgres connection is shared between more than one process or thread. Typical offenders are Resque workers or Unicorn. Be sure to correctly establish the PG connection after the fork or thread has initialized to resolve this issue.
> - Abrupt client (application side) disconnections. This can happen for many reasons, from your app crashing, to transient network availability. When your app tries to issue a query again against postgres, the connection is just gone, leading to a crash. When Heroku detects a crash, we migrate kill that dyno and start a new one, which re-establishes the connection.

I am seeing a similar problem, and while the above is helpful, I'd hope for a way to actually solve the problem (it seems sub-optimal if you can't stop a client from crashing the server). I've submitted a ticket to Heroku, so will advise if I find anything further...

UPDATE: Here is another link that might be relevant: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9421.

Comment: Postgres is not crashing here; it's reporting an error from the client side. "leading to a crash" means on the client side (dyno), not the Postgres server.