# Heroku: Regular 15 minutes downtimes on a simple Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, timeout

I'm new to Rails and just deployed my first app to Heroku (on the free tier). I set up a free trial of New Relic and set availability monitoring to ping my /register/ URL every 1 minute. I'm running Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3.

My app has basically no users and no requests (2 requests per minute, mostly coming from NewRelic). I have no background services or external dependencies. The data model is simple and no queries are taking more than a few 100ms.

I'm getting complete outages lasting exactly 15 minutes every few hours.

[image]

Since Heroku only keeps 1500 lines of logs I don't have data for each incident, but here's the log for the 2nd blip (my graph is -0400, Heroku is UTC).

**Full log:** https://gist.github.com/jbinto/5495226/raw/ba61ec16d9655287466cfbb9328f59c0171b2df7/heroku.log

**Summary**

- **00:56:21 through 01:00:21:** It chugs along with 1 request per minute as normal.
- **01:01:55:** The last request that came in, does not seem to be served.
- **01:02:21 through 01:17:21:** 54 H12 (request timeout) errors.
- **01:17:25:** PG::Error (SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected)   *(aside: I notice Heroku's log statements are out of order, weird.)*

Is this PG::Error the cause of my problems, or merely a symptom? Some Googling shows a discussion about Postgres timeouts on the starter tier, and some admonishment not using the production tier:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/heroku/a6iviwAFgdY

More StackOverflow:
[Postgres + Heroku SSL SYSCALL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420922/postgres-heroku-ssl-syscall-error)

And a Rails ticket about auto-reconnect:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9421

This looks to be a good clue, but nobody seems to have solved this. It seems there's some flakiness on Heroku's Postgres, and Rails<4 doesn't recover well from this.

- **01:17:26 through 01:17:27:** 58 GET requests are "served" (I imagine these are the queued requests? The client is long gone because of the 30 second timeout. Why are these requests still coming through?)
- **01:17:51:** Everything back to normal.

Any ideas? I'll be opening a Heroku support ticket, but not sure if I'll get anywhere as a free user.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is here:

`T01:02:21.144033+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=HEAD path=/register host=www.puckpicks.ca fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0`

You generally see this pattern where one long-running action starts hogging the queue for all further requests.

The Heroku router will drop a long-running request after 30 seconds, but the dyno behind it will continue processing the request until completion. The router is unaware of it, though, so it'll dispatch new requests to that busy dyno. This effect tends to compound, and you'll see queueing in New Relic and eventually H12 errors even for unrelated URLs, like static assets.

You may want to install something like rack-timeout, which will ensure that a long running request is dropped at the dyno-level as well. Specifically, rack-timeout raise a TimeoutError when that happens. https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout

With that in place, the compound effect is less likely to occur, but long-running actions still need to be addressed. New Relic is a great tool to provide the visibility into your app to identify the long-running actions. You can then optimize them and make sure they're able to finish within a reasonable time, I suggest keeping all requests under 500ms. If they're performing any inherently long tasks, you should try to offload those to a background worker.

If you have a higher traffic production application I also suggest that you use [Unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn) if you're not already so your app can process concurrent requests. This will give you more concurrency, help cut back on queue time, and give you more overall performance out of each dyno.

Comment: Thanks Neil. That explains why the log-jam of requests comes back after 15 minutes. I've deployed rack-timeout in hopes of preventing request queueing and getting a better stack-trace, but I still don't understand the root cause of the long-running requests. My app is simple, no external dependencies and when the app is running, no requests take over 100ms. My gut feeling is there's some flakiness with the connection between my Rails app and the Heroku Postgres (e.g. a stale connection that times out after ~15mins).